# How does grep work?

Tags: c, shell, unix, grep, gnu

I am trying to understand how `grep` works.

When I say `grep "hello" *.*`, does `grep` get 2 arguments — (1) string to be searched i.e. "hello" and (2) path `*.*`? Or does the shell convert `*.*` into something that `grep` can understand?

Where can I get source code of `grep`? I came across this [GNU `grep`](http://www.gnu.org/s/grep/devel.html) link. One of the README files says its different from `unix grep`. How so?

I want to look at source of FreeBSD version of `grep` and also Linux version of it (if they are different).

Comment: As a reference here is the UNIX man page for grep: http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?grep Here is the FreeBSD version: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep and here is the Linux version: http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep

Comment: A great place to browse old UNIX source code is http://www.tuhs.org

Comment: @luser droog: Thanks for the link, its amazing :)

Comment: @hari: If you're brave enough, take a look at the C compiler in version 3; it's truly frightening. Pointers are declared `a[]` rather than `*a`!

Comment: @luser droog: I can surely try! where can I look at that source?

Comment: @hari: I misremembered; it's from version 2. http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V2/c/ncc.c

Comment: you need to see this "where the Grep came from"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTfOnGZUZDk

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The shell does the globbing (conversion from `*` form to filenames). You can see this by if you have a simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And then run it like this:

```
./print_args *
```

You'll see it prints out what matched, not `*` literally. If you invoke it like this:

```
./print_args '*'
```

You'll see it gets a literal `*`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In case of `grep`, what does it get as second argument? list of files? or one file at a time?

Comment: @hari: Think about `grep` as that simple C program. If you give `grep` a `*`, it will end up with a bunch of filenames as extra arguments. If you quote the `*` like `'*'`, though, then the shell won't do globbing and `grep` will only get the single `*` argument (which will probably fail unless you have a file named exactly `*` in your current directory).

Comment: Wow, so if that particular dir has 1000 files, `*` would give it 1000 arguments? (each as a single file)?

Comment: @hari: Yes; try it. If you have a bunch of files you need to operate on like that, you may be better off using `find` and `xargs`.

Comment: Technically, `echo *` is more that sufficient to demonstrate the globbing.

Answer (score 22):

The power of `grep` is the magic of automata theory. GREP is an abbreviation for Global Regular Expression Print. And it works by constructing an automaton (a very simple "virtual machine": not Turing Complete); it then "executes" the automaton against the input stream.

The automaton is a graph or network of nodes or states. The transition between states is determined by the input character under scrutiny. Special automatons like `+` and `*` work by having transitions that loop back to themselves. Character classes like `[a-z]` are represented by a fan: one start node with branches for each character out to the "spokes"; and usually the spokes have a special "epsilon transition" to a single final state so it can be linked up with the next automaton to be built from the regular expression (the search string). The epsilon transitions allow a change of state without moving forward in the string being searched.

*Edit:* It appears I didn't read the question very closely.

When you type a command-line, it is first pre-processed by the shell. The shell performs alias substitutions and filename globbing. After substituting aliases (they're like macros), the shell chops up the command-line into a list of arguments (space-delimited). This argument list is passed to the `main()` function of the executable command program as an integer count (often called argc) and a pointer to a NULL-terminated (`(void *)0`) array of nul-terminated (`'\0'`) char arrays.

Individual commands make use of their arguments however they wish. But most Unix programs will print a friendly help message if given the `-h` argument (since it begins with a minus-sign, it's called an option). GNU software will also accept a "long-form" option `--help`.

Since there are a great many differences between different versions of Unix programs the most reliable way to discover the exact syntax that a program requires is to ask the program itself. If that doesn't tell you what you need (or it's too cryptic to understand), you should next check the *local* manpage (`man grep`). And for gnu software you can often get even more info from `info grep`.

Comment: Just a nit-pick: GREP is not an abbreviation for General Regular Expression Parser. It's a contraction of the vi/ex-mode command `:g/re/p` which stands for *global/regular expression/print*.

Comment: @Jens: `grep` predates `vi/ex` by a bit; it was the `ed` command `g/re/p` that it simulates, which was translated into `:g/re/p` in `vi` mode (and is also `g/re/p` in `ex`).  But the gist is correct.

Answer (score 6):

The shell expands the '`*.*`' into a list of file names and passes the expanded list of file names to the program such as `grep`.  The `grep` program itself does not do expansion of file names.

So, in answer to your question: `grep` does not get 2 arguments; the shell converts '`*.*`' into something `grep` can understand.

GNU `grep` is different from Unix `grep` in supporting extra options, such as `-w` and `-B` and `-A`.

It looks to me like FreeBSD uses the GNU version of `grep`:

- http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/8/gnu/usr.bin/grep/

Answer (score 3):

How grep sees the wildcard argument depends on your shell. (Standard) Bourne shell has a switch (-f) to disable file name [globbing](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) ([see man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bsh)).

You may activate this switch in a script with

```
set -f
```

Comment: Yes, but that's rarely used.  All (?) Unix/Linux shells do wildcard expansion by default.  And if you disable globbing and type `grep "hello" *.*`, `grep` will see `*.*` and treat it as a file name (and probably fail unless you happen to have a file with that name).